# Find likelihood function from Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that suicides occur in a population at a rate *p* per person
>   year and that *p* is assumed completely unknown. If we model the
>   number of suicides observed in a population with a total of *N* person
>   years as Poisson(*Np*), then record a representative likelihood
>   function for *p* when we observe $22$ suicides with  $N =30,345$.

The likelihood function is described as $L(\theta|x)=f_\theta(x)$ or in the context of the problem $L(p,N|x)=f_{p,N}(x)$.

I am a bit confused on how to interpret the actual numbers into this formula and the parameters. My guess is that the Poisson formula for this problem is $P(p,N)=\frac{p^Ne^{-p}}{N!}$. Therefore, would the likelihood function simply be this formula and plugging in the values $p = 22, N = 30,345$?

I think I may be misinterpreting the problem, and I am not quite sure how the Likelihood function differs from the probability density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a population for which you have observed $N$ person-years, the number of suicides is Poisson distributed with rate $\lambda = Np$, where $p$ is an unknown parameter representing the intensity of the Poisson rate for a single person-year.

That is to say, the probability of observing $x$ suicides in $N$ person-years is $$\Pr[X = x] = e^{-Np} \frac{(Np)^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots. \tag{1}$$

A likelihood function for $p$, given $N = 30345$ person-years observed and $X = 22$ observed suicides in that period, is proportional to the PMF:  $$\mathcal L(p \mid N, x) \propto e^{-Np} \frac{(Np)^x}{x!}, \tag{2}$$ and here, we can ignore any factors that are not functions of $p$; e.g., $$\mathcal L(p \mid N = 30345, x = 22) \propto e^{-30345p} p^{22}. \tag{3}$$

To address your question "how does a likelihood differ from a probability density," it is worth noting that the expression on the RHS of $(2)$ above is a probability mass function with respect to $x$ (as it is equivalent to $(1)$ above) but it is not necessarily a probability **density** with respect to $p$.  Notably, the **kernel** of the likelihood with respect to $p$ is proportional to a Gamma density, not Poisson.

As such, likelihoods can be constructed for fixed but unknown parameters and therefore do not need to be functions of a random variable.  While a Bayesian would regard these as proportional to posterior distributions of said parameters, a frequentist interpretation is still valid, e.g., when performing maximum likelihood estimation.

Moreover, a likelihood function is only unique up to a constant of proportionality, whereas a probability mass function or density must have total probability of $1$ over its support.